# How can I use different addresses to call functions in Hardhat tests and scripts?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

When running tests and scripts, all functions are called by the first address provided by Hardhat.

I'd like to know if there's a way to change the calling address within the same test or script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `connect()` method.

Code example from https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html#using-a-different-account

```
const [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();

// Transfer 50 tokens from owner to addr1
await hardhatToken.transfer(addr1.address, 50);

// Transfer 50 tokens from addr1 to addr2
await hardhatToken.connect(addr1).transfer(addr2.address, 50);
```